# posgres instance is listening to old port even after changing to new port number

Tags: windows, postgresql-12

My machine is having posgres server 11th version,for testing purpose i installed another posgres instance(12 version )in same machine.i changed port number of this new instance to 5433 but when i try to start its referring to old port number.
both the data folders are different.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Are you sure you changed the port in the correct config file? How are you starting Postgres 12?

Comment: windows 10.yes i changed port number in postgresql.conf file.i am starting manually from command prompt using pg_ctl command

Comment: The question was: did you change the number in the **correct** file? And how do you start Postgres 12?

Comment: yes it is correct file.am starting postgres 12 using pg_ctl command-->pg_ctl -D ..\data -l ..\pgsql.log start

Comment: If you specify the correct data directory that contains the correct config file, then it should use that port. Probably the port is defined a second time somewhere  in that file, or there is an included config file that overwrites that value.